# How to use multiple cursors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In [Brackets](http://brackets.io), you can use multiple cursors to edit code simply by holding `command` (on mac) and clicking on the text you want to edit (see it in action [here](https://youtu.be/QMoWNCdM6Yk?t=50s)). Is there a similar feature in Eclipse? Is there a way to do this without a plugin?

Answer (score 5):

You can try `Cmd+Alt+A` on mac. It lets you select a code block.  That's the nearest thing that I've found in eclipse.

In atom.io (another nice open source editor) you also have `Cmd+Click`

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse 4.22 (2021-12), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>) and other multi cursor (multi caret) actions are supported. See this answer to the same question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316624/1525602.